# Count if cell = X, based on data in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

My data shows how many orders clients have made over the last year.

- In column A, cells contain CAD, HEL or PBN (client types)
- In column C, cells contain the number of orders that client has made.

I require a formula which calculates how many CAD customers have made 1 order, how many have made 2-10 orders, etc.

This is what I've currently got:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A ="CAD",C:C="1")

=COUNTIF(A:A ="CAD",C:C=">10<2")
```

Please excuse my clear terribleness at Excel - trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `COUNTIFS` with an `"S"` for multiple conditions, so for just 1

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"CAD",C:C,1)`

....or between 2 and 10 inclusive

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"CAD",C:C,">=2",C:C,"<=10")`